# import error after installation of beautifulsoup in pycharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I use pycharm and created a scratch.py file. in this file I want to import beautifulsoup4. In pycharm I did use the project interpereter and added beautifulsoup4. 
After that I would expect to import the beautifulsoup4 package in my code but it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arthur/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 2, in <module>
    import beautifulsoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup'
```

I tried the command prompt and also succesfully installed with pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4

```
import os
import beautifulsoup
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) the right way to import Beautiful Soup 4 is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```